# ERROR : The multi-part identifier could not be bound, c# console Application

Tags: c#, sql, console-application

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("user id=ID;" +
                       "password=PASS;server=svr;" +
                       "Trusted_Connection=no;" +
                       "database=db; " +
                       "connection timeout=30");
                       cn.Open();
            SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand();

            command1.Connection = cn;
                     Console.WriteLine(ListofOrders.Count);
              for (int i = 0; i < ListofOrders.Count; i++)
                 command1.CommandText += string.Format("update table set Status='Expired' where GUID={0};", ListofOrders[i].ToString());

            command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    // LogicHandler.UpdateActiveOrders();
            Console.WriteLine("DONE", ConsoleColor.Cyan);
```

Getting error at this step: `command1.ExecuteNonQuery();` `Error Message: The multi-part identifier could not be bound.`

What i am trying here is I am running a select query and getting that data into the `ListofOrders` list from that I wanna run the update to those data in the list.

Please help

Comment: What is the data type of `ListofOrders`?

Comment: If you have a table named `table` you have to wrap it around square brackets: `[table]`.

Comment: better don't have a table `table` in the first place. And use apostrophes around `GUID='{0}'` or better use sql-parameters.
`

Answer (score 0):

If you use a [Reserved Keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) like `table` you have to wrap it in  square brackets: `[table]`. But it would be better to not use them in the first place.

I guess you need to wrap the `Guid` with apostrophes like in `GUID='{0}'`. Howver, you should use sql-parameters instead of string concatenation, always. That prevents also sql-injection.

```
string update = @"update tablename -- or [Table] but i wouldnt do that
                  set Status='Expired' 
                  where GUID=@GUID";
command1.CommandText = update;
command1.Parameters.Add("@GUID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = new Guid(ListofOrders[i].ToString());
```

As an aside, why have you used `command1.CommandText +=` instead of just `command1.CommandText =`? That is at least confusing, if you reuse the command it could also cause errors.